# VS Code task problem matcher for Angular CLI build/serve/test commands

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to configure VS code tasks for standard Angular CLI commands like `ng build`, `ng serve`, `ng test`. The purporse is to get a list of the problems, which I can easily traverse, when I run a CLI command. Currently I run these commands directly from the VS Code terminal, but sometimes it's difficult to navigate to an error because not all source links in the terminal are clickable. The VS Code problem list would be more convinient anyway. I wonder there still isn't a standard matcher, inspite the Angular is so popular, or I miss one?

I tried to create a custom matcher, but it looks harder than I expected. Angular CLI outputs typescript errors as well as html & scss errors, so the task should contain multiple matchers. I cannot use standard `$tsc` matcher, because the Angular CLI output slightly differs from the TS compiler output - the first error starts with `ERROR in` and this error isn't recognized by the `$tsc` matcher.

Here is `ng test` task for example, but it doesn't work as expected:

1. When I navigate to the first error by pressing `F8`, the problem list is cleared sometimes. I guess the matcher conflicts with the tsserver that detects error on a file open.
2. Sometimes the matcher misses some errors.

```
// .vscode/tasks.json

{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "label": "test",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "ng test",
        "problemMatcher": [{
            "base": "$tsc",
            "fileLocation": [
                "relative",
                "${workspaceRoot}/src"
            ],
            "pattern":[{
                "kind": "ts",
                "regexp": "^(?:ERROR in )?(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+) - (error|warning|info) TS(.*): (.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "code": 5,
                "message": 6
            }]
        }],
        "group": {
            "kind": "test",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: It gets even worse with Angular 9.... hope there is a solution

Comment: Nobody found a solution as of 2021 ?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem in Angular 11.
I found standard $tsc problem matcher in vscode source code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/149a8b71c534df0554c17b05cf1a925e9139c47f/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json#L1105)
and I also added the word Error to it at the beginning:

```
"problemMatcher": [
  {
    "base": "$tsc",
    "pattern": {
      "regexp": "^(Error: )?([^\\s].*)[\\(:](\\d+)[,:](\\d+)(?:\\):\\s+|\\s+-\\s+)(error|warning|info)\\s+TS(\\d+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$",
      "file": 2,
      "line": 3,
      "column": 4,
      "severity": 5,
      "code": 6,
      "message": 7
    }
  }
],
```

I also wrote about the problem [here](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/625)

Comment: Unfortunately, it stills says my task cannot be tracked, because the problem matcher is not defined, but it is. Why is that?